# How to define local variable for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, program-entry-point, self

Some of my commands work in rails console like this:

```
a = Player.new
a.download_files
a.play_songs
a.play_next
....
```

Every time, I need to run this code first:

```
a = Player.new
```

Can I define this variable to `Player.new` so that, after I enter rails console, I can work with `a.play_songs`?

Comment: What is the relation between `Play.new` and `Player.new`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should be Player.new.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot replace `self` in any situation.

However, you can define the methods `download_files`, `play_songs`, `play_next` on the `main` object so that you can call them without the explicit receiver `a`.

Comment: OK, how to define a new method on the main object? I know how to do it on the console, but how to define it inside rails app.

Comment: Define it in the main environment.

Comment: I made it! I added define a; @a ||= Player.new; end to environment.rb. Now a.play_songs works after I start the console.

Answer (score -2):

Could you replace `a` with `@a` and try again?

Comment: Requests for clarifications or suggestions have to be posted as comments. Answers are for posts that actually do answer the question.

Comment: This is not a clarification request. It's about an answer.